Best approach for HSTS with a redirect to a new domain
Situation:
A site we manage got migrated to a new hosted solution and will also have a new domain name. The clients want to keep the old domain name and have it redirect to the new domain name at the hosted solution (which we have basically no control over).
I've added a 301 redirect at the AWS Application Load Balancer level. It shunts traffic from the old url to the new url just fine. The problem though is that security folks mandate that the old url - if it is to continue - needs to respond with an HSTS header. This is a bit outside my wheelhouse, and I'm not coming up with a terrific solution for this.
The only workable solution that I can think of - haven't tested it yet, because I hope there is something better - is to maintain the server in the backend, have it provide an HSTS header before it gives the redirect. This seems like a bit much - maintaining a server just to add a header.
Reading documentation and other threads here, it doesn't sound like I can add an HSTS header directly to the ALB response.
I guess the options as I see them now are:

Convince the client to let the old domain go
Convince the security folks that the lack of HSTS on the old domain is OK
Keep a server running just to supply the HSTS (if that will even work)
Something else?


This is funny, I just had the same thing last month. TL;DR: fight them, you do not have a security vulnerability on a domain that’s only does a 301 redirect.
Actually the default security handbook covers the HSTS requirement for web servers serving websites. Since the old domain doesn’t serve websites, but just serves as a redirect, most security handbooks are ok with no HSTS. HSTS only really helps for actual webpages. There is no webpage here. There is no security issue. Security people work with checkboxes normally instead of knowing any of the technologies or why, so they may need it spelled out to them.
Additionally: your old domain does not serve HTTP websites at all, so having HSTS is pointless here too.
All in all, they should grant an exception on that checkbox on their spreadsheet, because lack of HSTS is not a security issue at all for a 301 redirect (or any other 3xx) and you are not serving any other traffic. And you are only serving websites on HTTP itself on the old domain either. Both of these make HSTS pointless.

Thanks so much. That was exactly what I was thinking, but I also had concerns that I was just overlooking something.
